# Electron App with Azure AD - without Interactive browser

Tags: azure-active-directory, electron, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Azure AD authentication with my Electron App (with Angular). I took reference from this link and able to integrate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop

Issue: It's using getTokenInteractive() method and it's navigating to an external browser. As per my requirement we don't have to navigate to an external browser, it should open the UI inside my electron App where end users can provide their credentials.
Another option if possible we can open the Azure AD url part of my electron App.

I took reference from this link and able to integrate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop

```
async getTokenInteractive(tokenRequest) {
        try {
            const openBrowser = async (url) => {
                await shell.openExternal(url);
            };

            const authResponse = await this.clientApplication.acquireTokenInteractive({
                ...tokenRequest,
                openBrowser,
                successTemplate: '<h1>Successfully signed in!</h1> <p>You can close this window now.</p>',
                errorTemplate: '<h1>Oops! Something went wrong</h1> <p>Check the console for more information.</p>',
            });

            return authResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see `shell.openExternal(url)` in the tutorial's code you've linked. Opening this URL in your `BrowserWindow`, i.e. using `win.loadURL(url)` should do the trick, but mind that you'll have to make sure that you navigate back to your app's webpages in time so that the renderer can actually receive the login event. But since you haven't shown any code of *yours*, this is as close to an answer as we'll get. Even if it's exactly the same, please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts. That tutorial may change in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I am using same as sample application

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner: could you provide any solution?

Comment: Did you try the approach from my comment above? If so, and if it worked, I could provide an answer with a theoretic explanation of that solution. However, this would still have strings attached and would only focus on how to *display* the login prompt inside the Electron app, nothing more.

Comment: I just replaced shell.openexternal with win.loadurl. But it's not working

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner: please provide the code snippet with your suggestion. As I mentioned in above code,if possible please make some changes and provide. That will be a great help.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work, then it doesn't work. I can't do debugging for this, thus I won't provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I imported BrowserWindows from electron and used the getAllWindows method to return all open windows, this method returns an array.

Hope this helps.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const openBrowser = async (url) => {
    const win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
    win[0].loadURL(url);
  };
```